# Xamarin Forms OAuth

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement OAuth authentication for a Xamarin.Forms POC project. In iOS project when i press Login button, App is redirecting to SSO page and is loading the Login Page but i am getting the following warning message. It is as follows

"scheme = https native UI with http[s] schema! redirect url will be loaded in native UI! OAuth Data Parsing might fail!"

here are the URL's

```
            clientId: "company ClientID",
            clientSecret: "company Secret",
            scope: "company profile",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://sso.companyname.com/sso/oauth2/authorize"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("dev.company.com"),
            accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://sso.companyname.com/sso/oauth2/access_token"),
```

URL Scheme i added in info.plist is "dev.company.com".

what does it mean and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect URI is not right - usually a value like com.mycompany.myapp:/callback is used - this is a Custom URI Scheme and should also be registered in the Authorization Server as an OAuth Client.

Also there should be no client secret - you should use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE).

OAuth for mobile apps is tricky - the AppAuth samples are a good place to start to understand the setup. A couple of posts on my blog describe how to run them:

- [Android sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup/)
- [iOS sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup/)